# What is the best statistical test for skewed distributions with different spread? (See image)

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, effect-size, skewness

I am working on an exercise in which I have to study how does one specific feature of a listing on a website for house rentals affects the number of reservations.

I plotted my kernel density estimator (similar to a histogram) for the number of reservations for each variant of the feature:
[image: KDEs]
I was thinking about doing a statistical test for the means, but since the distributions have such a different shape I am not sure if it is the best approach. Perhaps a statistical test for the medians would be more accurate?

I checked the distribution for the means of each one of the populations by randomly picking sub-samples and computing the mean and it looks Gaussian, so I think a t-test should be fine.

But since the shape of my distributions are clearly non-Gaussian, perhaps a non-parametric test would be a better choice?

Answer (score 1):

1. Since your observations are *counts* -- discrete and with a hard (and attained!) lower bound of 0, I wouldn't just blithely treat them as continuous by using a kernel density estimator to smooth them. [The behavior below 0 is particularly an artifact of the KDE.]
2. Allowing for the impact of the KDE, the shapes actually look somewhat similar to me (up to a different scale), but usually you wouldn't actually expect sets of counts to have the same shape (with the exception of samples from the geometric, which - at least sort of - does have the same shape).
3. In any case, if you want the same shape in order to use a nonparametric test, you'd only be looking for the same shape under the null; that is you don't necessarily expect the *samples* to look the same -- it's an assumption you'd want to hold when the null is true. The alternative can be more general in any number of ways where rejection would still be readily interpretable.
4. Since these are *counts* I'd first be looking for a test that is more suited to count data. For example, I might consider a Poisson or Negative Binomial model (perhaps via GLM).
5. That's not to say you shouldn't consider a nonparametric test, though, so if that's your preference, that should be fine. If you want to test means, that can still be done with a nonparametric test (via a permutation test, for example). With small counts you'll have a lot of ties, though (e.g. if you were to do a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney, make sure your software is dealing with the ties, not just assuming these values are continuous).
6. "I checked the distribution for the means of each one of the populations by randomly picking sub-samples and computing the mean and it looks Gaussian, so I think a t-test should be fine." -- it's not the distribution of the numerator, but the distribution of the t-statistic that matters. [Consider, for example, sample sizes of 30 from a Bernoulli(0.5). The numerator of a one-sample t-statistic looks fine, but because of the behavior of the denominator, the t-statistic itself is somewhat less like you'd expect it to be - the actual type I error rate is often quite different from the nominal rate across a large number of significance levels. e.g. at n=30, your 5% test is more like a 4.1% test, but at n=31 it's more like a 7.2% test!]